# Silent command line rendering

Tags: python, rendering, command-line

I'm using a simple script to create and render a scene and when I run the script from command-line as `blender --background --python hello.py` it prints lots of lines like:

```
Fra:1 Mem:7.99M (19.13M, Peak 27.65M) | Scene, Part 243-256
Fra:1 Mem:7.99M (19.16M, Peak 27.65M) | Scene, Part 244-256
Fra:1 Mem:7.99M (19.16M, Peak 27.65M) | Scene, Part 245-256
Fra:1 Mem:7.99M (19.16M, Peak 27.65M) | Scene, Part 246-256
Fra:1 Mem:7.99M (19.13M, Peak 27.65M) | Scene, Part 247-256
Fra:1 Mem:7.99M (19.13M, Peak 27.65M) | Scene, Part 248-256
Fra:1 Mem:7.99M (19.16M, Peak 27.65M) | Scene, Part 249-256
```

Please, does anyone know how to render silently, i.e. not verbose? `--verbose 0` didn't help...

Comment: No that is the normal rendering output. What OS and how does it interfere with what you want to do? there may be a way to get a result you can work with.

Comment: @sambler The script also prints to stdio so it's a bit hard to read (OS X).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can redirect `stdout` to `nul`:

```
blender --background --python hello.py 1> nul
```

In the script use `import sys` and one of the following to print to `stderr`:

- `print("blah blah", file = sys.stderr)`
- or `sys.stderr.write("blah blah")`
- or `sys.stdout = sys.stderr` at the start of the script and later `print("blah blah")`

Comment: @EcirHana does this solution work for you ?

Comment: I can't use sterr instead of sysout. Is there any other option?

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Is it possible to still have some sort of progress report when calling `bpy.ops.render.render(animation = True)`? Maybe like a nice status bar or something? I know, i'm spoiled. But that'd be rad! :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Chebhou's answer above, I also added this to my `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
alias blender='/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender'
function blender-python() {
    if [ "$1" == "-q" ] || [ "$1" == "--quiet" ] ; then
        blender "$2" --background --python "$3" 1> /dev/null
    else
        blender "$1" --background --python "$2" 1
    fi
}
```

This way I can call `blender-python` from the command line and, if I specify `-q` then it runs silently but if not it prints as usual. (The `1> /dev/null` redirects the output of `stdout` to the `/dev/null` dump instead of printing.)

Quiet output does require adding `sys.stdout = sys.stderr` above in the Python script, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to print your lines on blender but not the blenders so much of outputs, 
you can use add `your-command |grep "#"`.

"#" is a keyword **You can use you own keyword for this** that you can add at the beginning of statements you want to be printed.

Comment: But this prints only after full execution of the script. Is there a way to print while the script is being executed?

Comment: I beleive the linux piping | works on the go. as soon as the output from the previous command is available, it will be fed to the next as input, that is grep here in our case

Comment: atleast the grep piping is not working on the go. Does it for you?