# Cause Blender to cleanly exit with non-zero error code

Tags: python

I want to run a script in Blender in background mode. If the script fails, I want to print my own error and have Blender exit with a return code of `1`. I can do this:

```
print("script failed", file=sys.stderr)
sys.exit(1)
```

In older versions of Blender e.g. 2.69, this causes Blender to print stuff like:

```
Error: Not freed memory blocks: 5
IDProperty group len: 128 0x7f98be0ff938
TEXT_OT_run_script len: 168 0x7f98be064938
wmOperatorPtrRNA len: 24 0x7f98be5f1c18
IDProperty array dup len: 128 0x7f98be16deb8
wmOperatorReportList len: 40 0x7f98be0b1078

Blender quit
```

In 2.73a, it prints:

```
Error: Not freed memory blocks: 5
```

Which is better but not ideal, because it might make it hard for a user of my script to see what the real error is.

Is there a better way to make Blender exit?

Comment: maybe it would be easier to just hide the output : see this http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28646/5113

Comment: @Chebhou thanks - good suggestion, but `stderr` has a special meaning in the environment I'm using: it's for debugging and error messages. I suppose I could wrap the Blender execution in another script that redirects stuff from `stderr` to `stdout`... hoping not to though :)

Comment: you don't need to wrap blender execution, in the CMD call you add the redirect command `2>&1`